# How to exclude values from like statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query in SQL Server:

```
where description like '%' + client + '%'
```

And I have a table as follows:

```
client      | description
------------|-----------
Adam Juh    |one Adam Juh
Jorge Benne |rtg Jorge Benne
Ann Smith   |Ann 11.20
Judy For    |Judy For two
```

By using this query I can select where in "description" I have "client" with something before or after values in "client" column.

My question is: how to exclude certain values in the above SQL statement? For instance before or after values in "client" could be everything but not for instance statements like "one" or "two"?

I need as a result as:

```
client     |description
-----------|----------
Jorge Bene |rtg Jorge Benne
```

Because this record has in the description the name from the "client" column + something more but it something more is not "one" or "two".

How can I do it in SQL Statement?

Comment: `WHERE description LIKE '%client%' AND description NOT LIKE '%one%' AND desciption NOT LIKE '%two%'`

Comment: I eddited, question to more clarif

Comment: Mike de Bie, is it possible to give "one" and "two" to some list ? because what if I will have 100 this kin of warnings?

Comment: @gato please provide a [mre] i.e. set up a small example with **all** the tables involved... if you keep changing the requirements on us you're less likely to get an answer.

Comment: Answer of Mike de Bie is correct but only for 2 arguments but if I will have not only 2 argument but 100 is it possible to add some list ?

Comment: @gato I never worked with lists (arrays) in SQL before. This site has some information, maybe it can help you: https://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided `badwords` is a table of forbidden words

```
where description like '%' + client + '%' 
   and not exists (select 1
                   from badwords b
                   where description like '%' + b.word + '%')
```